# Laravel resourceful route error

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I get a resourceful route error which I can't comprehend.. so basically in my routes file this works :

```
Route::get('siswa', 'SiswaCont@index');
Route::get('siswa/create', 'SiswaCont@create');
Route::post('siswa', 'SiswaCont@store');
Route::get('siswa/{id}', 'SiswaCont@show');
Route::get('siswa/{id}/edit', 'SiswaCont@edit');
Route::patch('siswa/{id}', 'SiswaCont@update');
Route::delete('siswa/{id}', 'SiswaCont@destroy');
```

But when I changed it into one-line resource :

```
Route::resource('siswa', 'SiswaCont');
```

It produces NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 103 error, No query results for model [App\Siswa].

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: in which file do you insert your resource route? Inside `api.php` or `web.php`?

Comment: How do you check it's api or web?

Comment: This means there were no results found in the DB for the *Siswa* model. Check if you have records in the table and post the controller method that you're accessing.

Comment: @RayanSuryadikara wich version of Laravel are you using? in 5.3 inside routes folder you have api.php, console.php and web.php

Comment: It's 5.2.45 and there is no routes folder in app

Comment: There is a result, and index, create, and store works fine... rest are not so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When switching to a resource controller, don't forget that the parameter name **changes too**.

In your case the new routing would be `siswa/{siswa}`, not `siswa/{id}`.

When you want to keep your structure, use the following example:

```
Route::resource('siswa', 'SiswaCont', ['parameters' => [
    'siswa' => 'id'
]]);
```

The given code changes the default parameter of the ResourceController, which is the singularized version of you controller name (in your case *siswa*), to another developer-defined value (in this case *id*).

This will keep your current structure as the parameters are the same now and should fix your `NotFoundHttp` exception. More information concerning this code example can be found [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#naming-resource-route-parameters)

Comment: where do I change it? The working one is without using resource, the resource here is the problem..

Comment: @RayanSuryadikara I've added an example for keeping your parameter called id

Comment: @RayanSuryadikara Sure! I've added a few lines and a link to the laravel docs where it is explained even more in-depth.